# Two messages with the same sequence number

Tags: ros, rosbag, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file with a lot of messages on different topics. I've just found out that I have two messages with the same sequence number, but they were published to different topics. I thought that every message sent over ROS had a unique sequence number in the system, but, apparently, this isn't true.

What exactly is the sequence number used for? In which circumstances can we have two (or more) messages with the same sequence number?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261184/two-messages-with-the-same-sequence-number/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What exactly is the sequence number used for?

It's somewhat of a 'relic' from the earlier versions of ROS. The idea was that it could be useful to be able to correlate messages to each other, or deal with out-of-order delivery over transports that do not guarantee in-order delivery.

That never really got used (afaik), and on multiple occasions proposals to remove `seq` from `Header` have been put forth -- [ROS 2 RFC: Remove seq from Header.msg](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-ng-ros/_UFMxG5TG9s) on the `ros-sig-ng-ros` list being one of the more recent ones. That posting by @William also explains some of the shortcomings of `seq`, and might also answer some of your other questions about it.

> In which circumstances can we have two (or more) messages with the same sequence number?

There is no guarantee whatsoever that `seq` is unique, in any way. From the posting linked earlier:

> [..] in ROS 1, the `seq` field is sometimes set by the middleware, but inconsistently not set in other cases. For example, it is set when publishing, but not when sending a Service Request. Also, some client libraries don’t set the `seq` field on publish [..]

and:

> [..] `seq` is specific to a single publishing source, or topic depending on the middleware's behavior [..]

Uniqueness guarantees would also be really hard to implement robustly. Imagine a highly distributed system with 100+ hosts with tens of nodes of each. `seq` is a simple `uint32`, so setting up some oracle that can reliably generate unique nrs would be almost impossible due to the limited width of the integer and because of the necessity to somehow keep track of nrs already used across all involved graph participants.

So there can be many situations in which multiple msgs have identical sequence nrs. Most commonly it can occur if publishers (or the underlying client library) don't initialise `seq` at all (it stays `0`). In other cases `seq` could be set by the caller, who could happen to have started counting at the same nr (say `0`) as some other publishing entity in your node graph. This would also lead to the possibility of receiving different msgs with identical `seq` values.

In conclusion: no, `seq` is not required nor guaranteed to be unique - not even within a single process - and you should not rely on it being unique. It's only still there because of its history and for reasons of backwards compatibility. It probably won't be maintained as part of a `Header` (or equivalent structure) in ROS2 and if we could, it would've been removed from ROS1 a long time ago already.

---

Edit: found some related discussion: [Is the sequence number in Header message deprecated](https://discourse.ros.org/t/is-the-sequence-number-in-header-message-deprecated/1528/2) on ROS Discourse. The linked [ros2/common_interfaces#1](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/issues/1) on Github is also interesting, especially [this](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/issues/1#issuecomment-112621348) comment.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2017-05-06**:
Why isn't this fact about the deprecation of `seq` explicitly and very clearly written in the documentation: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-06**:
Honestly? I guess things change, are repurposed / updated over time and it only takes one person not doing their job in such a federated development model. This is going to sound a bit like a cliche, but a PR against [ros/std_msgs](https://github.com/ros/std_msgs) would be certainly be appreciated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-06**:
Also: I'm not sure the field *itself* is deprecated. It's more the fact that users should not assume that it's unique or consistently used everywhere. But I guess that's about the same.

I'm not a core developer, so all of this is assumptions and extrapolation on my part.